# CLOSE_WAIT and FIN_WAIT_2 when I try to create a SSL client socket

Tags: java, sockets, ssl, tcp

> The server port was listening correctly before I invoked this line:

`SSLSocket socket = (SSLSocket) ssFactory.createSocket(ipAddress, port);`

> Then it became like this:

1. TCP    0.0.0.0:23333          0.0.0.0:0              LISTENING
2. TCP    10.200.49.196:23333    10.200.49.196:50814    FIN_WAIT_2
3. TCP    10.200.49.196:50814    10.200.49.196:23333    CLOSE_WAIT

> I never wanted to close the port. Why did it hang like that? The code worked fine before.

Comment: Looks like you had a previous connection from the same client port.

Comment: The server at 10.200.49.196:23333 has said it has no more data to send.  The client at 10.200.49.196:50814 can still send data.  Is this unexpected?  We need more information on what you expected, what happened, and what your code is..

Answer (score 0):

I can not ask as comment. :(

Did the certificate change and the SSL hand shake failed? This may result in a closed SSL connection.

The `netstat` output shows:

- a running server socket
- a client to server entry of a closed connection
- and a server to client entry of a closed connection

Is there any exception thrown?